# Algorithm using time intervals

Tags: algorithm, swift

I am trying to create an algorithm that would increase the value of my second variable: "level" every 5 seconds, but I am stuck.

```
// This algorithm wll instill the point system in the game
    let nextLevel = SKAction.waitForDuration(NSTimeInterval(5.0))
    //*Pseudocode: Level increases every 5 seconds
   // let level =
```

Comment: ...this is easy to do: Create a variable with the current system time. create a new thread that checks to see what time it is by comparing current time with your variable. if the difference is 5 seconds update your variable and do whatever else you need to do every 5 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

Use timers!

```
    timer = new Timer(5000, increment_var);
    timer.start(); 

    public int increment_var{
        level++;
    }
```